# Saving existing file: empty value attribute is removed

Tags: c#, save, config

I have a config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="value1" />
    <add key="key2" value="" />
    ...
  </appSettings>    
  ...
</configuration>
```

I read the config, change the value of key1 and save the config

```
System.Configuration.Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Configuration.ConfigFile.Replace(".config", string.Empty));
appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["key1].Value = "newvalue1";
appConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

After this I get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="newvalue1" />
    <add key="key2"/>
    ...
  </appSettings>    
  ...
</configuration>
```

Why is the 'empty' value attribute removed for key "key2"?
When I try it with

```
appConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

, the attribute is not removed. But I want to know why it's removed in the first case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<add key="key2" value="" />
```

and

```
<add key="key2" />
```

are both functionally equal.  The value of key2 with or without that tag is a null string variable which is equivalent to the empty string.

---

Edit to reflect comment:  Simply assign key2 the empty string in the same statement.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration appConfig =  ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Configuration.ConfigFile.Replace(".config", string.Empty));
appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["key1"].Value = "newvalue1";
appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["key2"].Value = "";
appConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

---

Second Edit for 2nd comment:

Well, you haven't provided enough information then.  All of my answers answer your question.  The two values from the first answer are functionally equivalent.  Therefore, if you wish to see if the "key2" value = "" then you could simply run the following

```
if(appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["key2"] == null){
    //If this hits, that means <add key="key2" value="" />
}
```

Please research how to ask a good question and adjust your question to reflect what you are really trying to ask.

Comment: Thanks but we check in another part on the value attribute of the config file by reading it as xml, so we need the value attribute with an empty string

Comment: thanks for the update. But it's not possible to update key2 to an empty string. It's an update program that updates some properties of the config file.

Comment: @WernerKellens your question has now been answered 3 times.  Please update your question to reflect what you really want to know or mark this as accepted and ask a separate question.

Comment: The question is why it's removed when we call save with ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal  (doc: Causes only properties that differ from inherited values to be written to the configuration file.) and not removed with ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified (doc: Causes only modified properties to be written to the configuration file, even when the value is the same as the inherited value)? After reading the documentation of 
Minimal I think he shouldn't update key2 because this value isn't changed.

Comment: @WernerKellens The minimal save mode causes the empty value string to be overwritten because of a programming property called "Short Circuiting".  After the method parses your config and sees that its an empty value, its alters the config in the most minimal possible way.

Comment: Thanks for your help!